# Is it possible to modify an external source from the <head> in an iFrame on load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

Thanks in advance for helping out. It has been bugging me for a while and I believe it can be very useful for others who don't, to know how to, if possible, modify an head of an iframe of external location, in example:

```
<iframe src="http://www.somewebsite.com/someresourceid?=123" width="500" height="700" scrolling ="yes">
```

This iframe has ofcourse it's own head and body loaded into the page. Now is it possible for example to change in it's head the following:

```
<script src="http://www.someotherwebsite.com/somescript.js?id=789" type="text/javascript">
```

Desired change is to change ?id from 789 to 456.

Since we are already discussing it, is it also possible to completely remove this line of script, or prevent this script from loading at all?

Just to for reference in this case my website is none of both, it would be just:

```
www.website.com
```

Best Regards!

Comment: Please read this: [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Information there is in my opinion relevant, yet irrelevant to the exact question. In our case the iFrame and all it's contents are loading fine on website.com, we just wish to modify what their head is loading, or prevent to load particular scripts, such as potential malware ads .js. I very much appreciate your response, please help if you can.

Comment: @inder.gg — Your question is, essentially, "How can my page modify a page from a different origin?" — why do you think the same origin policy is irrelevant?

Comment: I am not a pro, however I believe this page is telling me what is possible to add to a page CrossDomain or not. I don't see where it explains "how to" block or modify a certain piece of text, which essentially would change what is loaded or not. Can you please be more clear, this didn't help me at all.

Comment: @inder.gg — The same origin policy is not about "adding to" a page. It is about interacting with it in any way at all.

Answer (score 2):

No.

1. You can't modify the HTML of a page as it is being loaded in an iframe. You can only manipulate elements in the DOM after they have been added to it, by which time it is too late to prevent script execution.
2. The [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevents you from accessing the document on the other origin anyway.

The closest you could come would be to use server side code to copy the document, modify it, and give it a URL on a server you control and then give that URL to the browser in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. So this essentially means, it is not possible to change the ?id=789 to ?id=456 in the head of an iframe on external url, through php or javascript/ajax/jquery on my page? :(

Comment: Using PHP could you use the approach mentioned in the last paragraph of the answer. You can't instruct your visitors' browsers to modify other people's pages though.

Comment: Thanks for your help, in this case it might not be possible then, as we were more targetting for url-rewrite/php-replaces/ajax-jquery-js-targetted-replaces-or-stops. As the content of the iframe is video through JWPlayer.